# Android ContentProvider - multiple cursors with notification observers

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

My application includes SQLite with `ContentProvider`, `LoaderManager<Cursor>` and multiple tables in database. Problem I've got is that I cannot set notification on multiple URI's. So when I'm making changes in DB by inserting or updating I want to call `getContentResolver().notifyChange()` with appropriate URI, but it listens to only one URI at the time. How can I manage it to react to changes in multiple tables at once?

Content's provider query class when I'm setting notification on URI's

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case NOTES:
            queryBuilder.setTables(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_NOTES);
            break;
        case NOTES_ID:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case CHECKLISTS:
            queryBuilder.setTables(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_CHECKLISTS);
            break;
        case CHECKLISTS_ID:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case CHECKLIST_ITEMS:
            queryBuilder.setTables(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_CHECKLIST_ITEMS);
            break;
        case CHECKLIST_ITEMS_ID:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection,
            selection, null, null, null,
            DBOpenHelper.GRID_POSITION + " ASC");
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

And the methods where I'm calling notify changes

```
public static void insertNote(Activity activity, String noteText, int stickerId, int backgroundId) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT, noteText);
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.BACKGROUND_ID, backgroundId);
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.STICKER_ID, stickerId);
    activity.getContentResolver()
            .insert(CursorProvider.CONTENT_URI_NOTES, values);
    activity.getContentResolver().notifyChange(CursorProvider.CONTENT_URI_NOTES, null);
}

public static void insertChecklist(Activity activity, List<ChecklistItem> checklistItems, int stickerId, int backgroundId) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.BACKGROUND_ID, backgroundId);
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.STICKER_ID, stickerId);
    Uri uri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(CursorProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHECKLISTS, values);
    long id = Long.valueOf(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    for(ChecklistItem item : checklistItems) {
        values.clear();
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.CHECKLIST_ITEM_TEXT, item.getChecklistItemText());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.CHECKLIST_ID, id);
        activity.getContentResolver().insert(CursorProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHECKLIST_ITEMS, values);
    }
    activity.getContentResolver().notifyChange(CursorProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHECKLISTS, null);
}
```

Effect of this code is that when it's working for notes it doesn't work for checklists and vice versa. That depends on which I'm setting first, the second one is not registered.

Comment: when calling `setNotificationUri` / `notifyChange` you dont have to use the same `Uri` that was passed to your custom `CP`: it may be any "common" to notes and checklists `Uri`, what are your final `Uri`s? something like content://bla.bla.bla/notes/<NOTE_ID>,  content://bla.bla.bla/checklists/<CHECKLIST_ID>?

Comment: Exactly, it looks like that content://package/checklists/checklistId. How to build "common" uri when paths to notes and checklists are different?

Comment: you could try something like this: `content://package/common` and: `content://package/common/checklists/checklistId`, `content://package/common/note/noteId` etc and `notifyChange` with `content://package/common`

Comment: If I understand that correctly when it hits commons I can make case for it in my switch? but I would have to use raw query for querying all tables in one cursor, and that won't be good for my cursor handling code. Can I somehow make it with seprate query for each table? Or get somehow data from uri which table need to be queried with that call? EDIT: I did that with raw query, but unfortunately it flips my code when I'm trying to read cursor

Comment: i mean if you are calling two `queries` with `Uri` (for simplicity i will use only `path` of the `Uri`) `common/notes/` and `common/checklists/` and call `notifyChange` with `common/` both loaders will be reloaded

Comment: It works! I found some errors in my cursor handling code but the notification mechanism works, it calls all loaders. Thank You, You are more than welcome to post this as an answer :) One more small quesiton, is it necessary to set notification uri on every query? Or can I set it only once?

Comment: you have to set it for a cursor, so if every time a new cursor is created then you need to set notification on it